# Получение местоположения из Location API

Tags: геолокация, android

Добрый день,

Разбираюсь с примерами на главном сайте Android, а конкретно с [этим](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). Запустил, работает, но только если включен прием от спутников GPS.
Так вот хотел поинтересоваться у опытных специалистов, можно ли, используя Location API,принимать данные не только от GPS, а и от вышек сотового оператора и WiFi-подключений?

Comment: да, можно, там это написано должно быть

Comment: не нашел, поэтому и написал сюда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Если в настройках телефона прописано получать только от GPS - он и получает только от GPS. Включил получать данные от CellID и WiFi, и, о счастье, координаты стали приходить. Всем спасибо, всем по плюсу.

Answer (score 1):

просто нужно выбрать какой провайдер использовать NETWORK_PROVIDER или GPS_PROVIDER
Смотри в доках
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html